# Problem which receiving emits inside a popup window Vue3

Tags: components, vuejs3, eventemitter

I have a project in Vue3 with components

- Welcome.vue
- popupWindow.vue
- App.vue

I have a problem with receiving emits in the popup window component

PopupWindow is shown upon emitting:

```
emitter.emit('showPopupWindow', false)
```

It is emitted in welcome.vue

And the popup fires in app.vue:

```
<popup-window v-if="isPopupWindowVisible" class="popup-window"/>
```

In `welcome.vue`, when the button is pressed, it calls functions:

```
        async updatePosition() {
            const { latitude, longitude } = await this.getPosition();
            this.latitude = latitude;
            this.longitude = longitude;
            console.log("location updated");
            this.emitLocation();
        },
```

which is waiting for data from:

```
        async getPosition() {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
                position => {
                    const { latitude, longitude } = position.coords;
                    resolve({ latitude, longitude });
                    console.log("location get")
                },
                error => {
                    reject(error);
                }
                );
            })
        },
```

Then I would like to pass this information to the popup window component in which the leaflet map is located.

I did it with the function:

```
        emitLocation() {
            const latitude = this.latitude
            const longitude = this.longitude
            emitter.emit('showPopupWindow', true)
            emitter.emit('latitude', latitude);
            emitter.emit('longitude', longitude);
        },
```

Which emitted `showPopupWindow` to make the popup display.

It then emitted long years data.

In the mounted popup component, I try to receive this data using the

```
    emitter.on('latitude', (data) => {
        console.log("Location received",data)
        this.latitude = data;
    });
    emitter.on('longitude', (data) => {
        console.log("Location received",data)
        this.longitude = data;
    });
```

And assign them to the attributes of data()

After loading the page for the first time and clicking on the button firing it up, I get these logs:

```
location get
location updated
```

Lat and Long are emitted (I checked this by adding `console.log()` to `emitLocation()` ).

Unfortunately, on the first approach they are not received by the popup even though it is already mounted on the page

After turning off the popup and turning it back on, I get these logs

```
location get
location updated

Location received 52.114762
Location received 20.8922374
```

So everything works as it should.

However, I have no idea how to approach this so that it works on the first click after loading the page.

Additionally, even on the 2nd attempt when data is received'

For example

```
this.latitude = data;
```

data from emit is not assigned to Data() of my component.

Comment: In addition, I have tried approaches such as delaying the sending of emits until the component popup window is mounted and sending an emit "Mounted" to the component welcome.vue which then confirms that the popup has mounted itself

Comment: Hard to say without setting this up. I think you'd be better having two events emitted; showPopup with payload consisting of lat lng, and hidePopup with no payload.

Comment: You say that the popup is already mounted - how can that be if showPopupWindow event is emitted right before two others? Emits will work synchronously but the component mounts on nextTick.

Comment: why not emits in welcome-component instead of setting emit-callback-function as param of the pop modal component?If so, it will trigger directly.